# Is there a way of using ctrl-r after typing part of command in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, key-binding, readline

In bash the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> command is very useful, I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> `whatever` and it searchs my history for commands containing the word `whatever`. But if I type `whatever` and realize that I would like search that word and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> nothing happens.

Is there a way hitting a key and having it behaving as if I had typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> `whatever` instead of `whatever` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>?

I have the following in my `.inputrc`:

```
"\C-p": history-search-backward
```

but this only works if the beginning of the line is the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can search bash's history using what you have already typed easily.

Suppose you have just typed `curl -I http://superuser.com` and you forgot to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> first:

```
$ curl -I http://superuser.com
```

If you want to do an i-search on your history, **go to the beginning of line *first*** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>), enter i-search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>. This should search using the contents of the whole text you already typed:

```
(reverse-i-search)`curl -I http://superuser.com': curl -I http://superuser.com/faq
```

Alternatively, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> to search using just the first word of the text you just typed:

```
(reverse-i-search)`curl': curl -I http://superuser.com/faq
```

### Binding it all to a single key

If you want to do all this in one keystroke, you can bind a single key to a keyboard macro. If you want to use, say, <kbd>F12</kbd> run:

```
$ bind '"\e[24~":"\C-a\C-r\C-y"'
```

That will last for the session.

### Making it permanent

Just define the macro in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[24~":"\C-a\C-r\C-y"
```

Note that here we **omit** the single quotes.

You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4201274/1792488) useful.

Comment: I am not sure if it is a problem with my configuration, but after I type `c-r` typing `c-y` does not paste anything there. If I type `c-y` by itself just pastes the text, so I cannot combine the two commands...

Comment: Do you go to beginning of line first? (C-a)

Comment: You are right, I wasn't going to beginning of line. Now I have in my .inputrc `"\C-xr": "\C-a\C-r\C-y"` and it works very nice! Thanks for this answer.

Comment: I think it is the third time I googled this `control+a control+r control+y` thing! Thanks this answer is always here! :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Save four strikes:

Avoid a second `Ctrl-R` by adding to your `.bashrc` (or to your `.inputrc` if you prefer):

```
bind '"\er":"\C-a\C-r\C-y\C-r"' # alt-r = ctr-a ctr-r ctr-y ctr-r
```

This will map **ALT-R** to **CTR-A CTR-R CTR-Y CTR-R**

#### Description:

- **ALT-R**: the binding key. Another good option is `\C-xr` (**CTR-X CTR-R**)
- **CTR-A**: Go to the begin of the line (memorizing what is written)
- **CTR-R**: Start the reverse search
- **CTR-Y**: Paste what **CTR-A** memorized as part of the search
- **CTR-R**: Triggers the reverse search with the characters so far

Comment: It still not clear to me why C-y pastes the command onto the search field (C-a is not supposed to be a "copy" command, is it?) and why C-w pastes only the first word.

Comment: yes, `C-a` not only moves, but memorize (copy) the content moved over.

Comment: I can't confirm that behavior (just try C-a C-y), I think it's more likely that C-r that has some special cases built in, but I don't know where they're documented.